# performBatchUpdates некорректно работает с секциями в UICollectionView iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Мое приложение напоминает Apple Books: когда пользователь удаляет книгу из верхней полки, то освободившееся место заполняет книга из нижней полки. И всё это должно быть с анимацией. 
Внешний вид моего приложения выглядит так (внизу будут скриншоты интерфейса с пояснениями): есть UICollectionView с двумя секциями (section 0, section 1). В каждой секции 5 предметов (items). При попытке удалить предмет из второй секции (section 1) - все срабатывает идеально. Но вот когда я удаляю предмет из верхней секции (section 0), то получаю следующую ошибку:

> invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in
>   an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number
>   of items contained in that section before the update (5), plus or
>   minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0
>   inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into
>   or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Я всё делаю по инструкции: 1.удаляю мой предмет из базы данных (Core Data), 2.обновляю массив с предметами, 3.удаляю предмет из collectionView. Вот код с этими действиями:

```
extension MainCollectionViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            items = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Item]
            items2 = items.chunked(into: 5)

            self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [self.deletedItemIndex!])
        })
    }
}

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Функция chunked работает следующим образом: она создает в массиве подмассивы, где каждый подмассив ассоциируется с секцией. Выглядит это так:

До chunked:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] //исходный массив items
```

После chunked (массив items2):

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // первая секция (section 0) в collectionView
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], // вторая секция (section 1) в collectionView
]
```

Так, например, если удалить число 3 из исходного массива (items) и применить к этому массиву функцию chunked, то массив items2 получит такой вид:

```
[
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], // первая секция (section 0) в collectionView
    [7, 8, 9, 10], // вторая секция (section 1) в collectionView
]
```

Таким образом, первый подмассив всегда инициализируется 5 элементами. Заполнение коллекции выглядит так (всё просто):

```
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        print("call numberOfSections")
        //3
        return items2.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("call numberOfItemsInSection, current section is \(section)")
        //4
        return items2[section].count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let item = items2[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.itemNameTextLabel.text = item.name
        cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(data: item.image! as Data)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Удаление предмета происходит после долгого нажатия на него (тут тоже тривиальный код):

```
@objc func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {
    if gesture.state != .ended {
        return
    }

    let p = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: p) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", self.items2[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name!)

        do {
            if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
                let selectedItem = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)[0]
                //save deleted item index in var that use it index in performBatchUpdatesBlock
                deletedItemIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)

                context.delete(selectedItem)

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    print("Save!")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Oh, error! \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Массив items2 корректно обновляется, если удалить из первой секции (section 0) какой-нибудь предмет (предметов станет 4), это можно увидеть, если прописать такую строчку

```
print(self.items2[0].indices)
```

в методе performBatchUpdates после строки

```
items2 = items.chunked(into: 5)
```

(то есть, после обновления массива items2). Результат будет

```
0..<5
```

то есть первый подмассив взял элемент из второго подмассива и присвоил его себе, все как нужно! Но почему-то приложение крашится с приведенной ошибкой... Вот картинка с интерфейсом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в методе performBatchUpdates прописать такой код (предварительно удалив старый код внутри этого метода):

```
items2[deletedItemIndex!.section].remove(at: deletedItemIndex!.row)

self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [self.deletedItemIndex!])
```

то результат будет таким (тут показан результат уже после того, как юзер удалил картошку из первой секции):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Массив items2 обновился (но не заполнил свои пустые ячейки в первой секции, так как мы его об этом и не просили) и метод numberOfItemsInSection сработал корректно (так как мы не просили его вернуть 5 элементов), но вот при попытке отсортировать этот массив (применив функцию chunked), чтобы в его первой секции было 5 элементов - происходит эта ошибка.

Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/ArtyomGrigoryan/CollectionViewWithSectionsDemo/blob/master/CollectionViewWithSectionsDemo/MainCollectionViewController.swift) на ГитХаб с проектом (если будете запускать, то на симуляторе iPhone SE, пожалуйста). Данные прописаны в items.plist и автоматически сохранятся в вашу локальную БД при первом запуске приложения.

Вопрос: что не так с моим кодом?

Comment: Образец шикарно поставленного вопроса.

Comment: @VAndrJ а это вы с сарказмом?)

Comment: Нет, я серьезно. Все расписано, примеры кода в вопросе, скрины результата, ошибка, проект с воспроизводящейся ошибкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у Вас с тем, что Вы удаляете элемент:

```
self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [self.deletedItemIndex!])
```

По остальному же описанию, количество должно оставаться неизменным в этой секции. Таким образом `UICollectionView` ожидает, что должно быть уже 4 элемента, но их все так же остается 5. Варианты решения:

1. Правильно заменять. Т.е. при удалении последней ячейки в первой секции Вы должны "подвинуть" первую ячейку второй секции на ее место, а все ячейки второй сдвинуть к началу секции и последнюю ячейку второй секции удалить. Метод

   moveItem(at:to:)
2. Использовать, к примеру, [Differ](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Differ), который все просчитает за Вас.
   Сделал pull request с примером. Ссылка на форк:

[GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/CollectionViewWithSectionsDemo)

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш совет! метод moveItem(at:to:) получается, что я в перформБатче должен буду создать цикл, где буду сдвигать ячейки этим методом? Я просто никогда не использовал метод мувАйтем

Comment: понял вас. А Differ это... это что?) Если у вас, конечно, есть время для объяснения

Comment: @Tkas Это одна из библиотек, которая облегчает жизнь. В примере найдите строчку `collectionView?.animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData: oldData, newData: items2)`. Т.е. передали старые данные, передали новые, оно все обсчитало и удалило/добавило/подвинуло.

Comment: то есть вот эта строка collectionView.animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData: old, newData: new) эквивалентнта циклу с мувАйтем?

Comment: установил Differ, но вот проблема: он делает reloadData (я не вижу анимации)

Comment: Я посмотрел в коде Differ, но там нигде reloadData не вызывается. Не понмаю что происходит.

Comment: @Tkas добавил правки с комментариями, чтобы были анимации сдвига. Перезагрузка секциями вызвана тем, что при сравнении обычных массивов он видит, что массивы разные и перезагружает всю секцию. С дополнительной оберткой мы указываем как быть с секциями, а с элементами уже само.

Comment: да, теперь всё работает идеально. Благодарю вас за помощь и подробное объяснение сути происходящего!